# adding arguments to a function before calling that function - node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

say I have a function:

```
function foo(){
console.log(arguments);
}

process.nextTick(foo);
```

how can I apply arguments to foo in the `process.nextTick()` call?

how do I do something like

//pseudo code

```
var args = [];
process.nextTick(foo.addArgs(args));
```

...but without calling foo?

Comment: w/Array: `Function.apply.bind( foo, null, ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few possibilities. For the first several options, I'm (perhaps wrongly) assuming that you don't mind passing `args` as a single array parameter. If you want each element of `args` to be a separate argument to `foo()`, see the last example (using `apply()`).

Assuming you don't use `this` inside of `foo()`, here are some options:

```
process.nextTick(function () { 
  foo(args); 
});
```

Or:

```
var bar = foo.bind(null, args);
process.nextTick(bar);
```

If you use `this` inside of `foo()`, change `null` in the above example to the value that you expect `this` to have. For example:

```
var bar = foo.bind(foo, args);
process.nextTick(bar);
```

You may also wish to look at [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). `apply()` is especially useful if you want to have an array (say, `[1, 2, 7]`) that you want spread out across the function args (that is to say, `foo(1, 2, 7)` instead of `foo([1, 2, 7])`):

```
process.nextTick(function () {
    foo.apply(null, args);
}
```

As with `bind()`, if you use `this` inside of `foo`, then change `null` in the above example to be the value that you expect `this` to have.

Comment: this seems fairly legit

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with an anonymous function:

```
var args = [];
process.nextTick(function(){
   foo.apply(foo, args);
});
```

Comment: this is the most straightforward solution, but I want to know other ways to do it as well